# PHP Start loop in one function and end it in another?

Tags: php

I'm building my personal Database connection model and one thing that I needed to do is allow the user to start a loop using a function and end the loop in another function. This is the code:

Code for running the functions

```
PSMQuery::loopQueryStart("DATA");
  // Stuff that can be executed in the loop
PSMQuery::loopQueryStop();
```

Code in the class:

```
public function loopQueryStart($query) {
  while (CONDITION):
}

public function loopQueryEnd() {
  endwhile;
}
```

And I was wondering if this method should work and if there would be another way, just to simplify the look of the code for someone using my model.

Comment: what the hell are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Federico a loop being started with a function, the in the middle the user can use their input then another function which will close the loop. - kind of like the CodeIgniter method for Auth

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Can't you just pass a function/reference to, eg `PSMQuery::loop("Data", function($var) { /* sth */})`?

Comment: You can't do it. Blocks have to be properly nested.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have your loopQueryEnd function make the `CONDITION` false, thus ending the while loop?

Comment: @kingkero What type of thing do I look up on how to use functions in functions? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, I do not think this is a good idea. Yes, WordPress' loop comes to mind, but it just feels dirty to me.

What I would suggest are [Callbacks / Callables](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php). This way you do not need to start and end the loop in different functions and can simply pass a function to call inside the loop. I have prepared [this working example](https://3v4l.org/9nm6O). Your code could look like this

```
PSMQuery::loopQuery("Data", function($data) {
    // return something
});

//***

public static function loopQuery($data, callable $callback) {
   while (loop) {
       // do something with $callback
   }
}
```

If you want to manipulate in a more complex way, [references](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.references.php) might help you find a solution

Comment: After being confused for a while I finally got it, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @kero Still I would opt and drag about @JackHales soslution. Take for example wordpress. It would be much cleaner to have php structure like `start_loop(); echo $title; end_loop()`.

Comment: @PawełWitek Even with WP you'd usually do `while (have_posts()) { the_post(); /* your code */ }`. In the end it is more a question of style of code I'd say - and I stick with my original message, that I prefer it with a callback, this way it is all combined and not one method call here, another one somewhere else.

Comment: @kero yes, you're right, I do that by myself, I've created snippet to print this out for ease of use and its easy however my thinking is purly esthetics :) and I wonder if this open / close loop functions are even possible? have a great day! ^^

Comment: @PawełWitek In templating you usually do it like this, that your calls get transpiled to `while():` and `endwhile;`. With this, you can restructure it around multiple files/calls/whatever, but for me it always feels just too messy

Comment: Guys I've moved off PHP years ago, no stress about this. FYI this looping is disgusting, no one should do it. @kero